# How to return numpy.array object from a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, backtracking

This program uses backtracking to solve sudoku. The input matrix is a `numpy.array` object.

## Program:

```
import numpy as np
sudoku_matrix = np.array([[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
                          [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                          [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
                          [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                          [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]])
number_list = [x for x in range(1, 10)]


def possible_number(a, b, number):
    x1, y1 = (a // 3) * 3, (b // 3) * 3
    flag = False
    sub_array = sudoku_matrix[x1:(x1 + 3), y1:(y1 + 3)]
    if number not in sudoku_matrix[a]:
        if number not in sudoku_matrix[:, [b]]:
            for x in sub_array:
                if number in x:
                    flag = True
                    break
            if flag == False:
                return True
    return False


def solver():
    for a in range(0, 9):
        for b in range(0, 9):
            if sudoku_matrix[a][b] == 0:
                for number in number_list:
                    if possible_number(a, b, number):
                        sudoku_matrix[a][b] = number
                        solver()
                        sudoku_matrix[a][b] = 0
                return
    return sudoku_matrix 
    # print(sudoku_matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(solver())
```

If you print the result in the `solver()`, it successfully prints to stdout, but when you return `sudoku_matrix`, it returns `None`. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have an additional `return` inside the nested loop which is eventually reached. This returns `None`.

Comment: You have two `return` statements.  Which one is returning the final case?  Don't just assume - verify

Comment: @hpaulj 
The first return statement returns to the previous function call. It never returns to the main function call. The second return statement is executed only once when there are no zeros in the `sudoku_matrix`. 
The second return should return the final answer. It prints the result but cannot return it.

Comment: @a_guest Its true that the nested loop `return` statement returns `None`. But the intention of this statement is to get back to the previous function call not to return the final value (in my case `sudoku_matrix`).
If you replace `return` with `print`, it works well.

Comment: Argue with the code, not us.  Change the bare `return` to `return 'I am wrong'` and report back.